# Disable access to Firefox API in Console

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I need to deploy Firefox and prevent users from doing `Cu.import` calls from the web console.

Is this possible at all? If yes, is there a simple way to achieve this setting an `about:config` pref?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Firefox 57 this question is no longer relevant.

For earlier releases, there seems to be no mechanism to prevent the described behaviour.